# Trouble calling EMBOSS program from python

Tags: python, subprocess, biopython, emboss

I am having trouble calling an EMBOSS program (which runs via command line) called sixpack through Python.

I run Python via Windows 7, Python version 3.23, Biopython version 1.59, EMBOSS version 6.4.0.4. Sixpack is used to translate a DNA sequence in all six reading frames and creates two files as output; a sequence file identifying ORFs, and a file containing the protein sequences.

There are three required arguments which I can successfully call from command line: (`-sequence [input file]`, `-outseq [output sequence file]`, `-outfile [protein sequence file]`). I have been using the subprocess module in place of os.system as I have read that it is more powerful and versatile.

The following is my python code, which runs without error but does not produce the desired output files.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import re
import os
import subprocess

infile = input('Full path to EXISTING .fasta file would you like to open: ')
outdir = input('NEW Directory to write outfiles to: ')
os.mkdir(outdir)
for record in SeqIO.parse(infile, "fasta"):

    print("Translating (6-Frame): " + record.id)

    ident=re.sub("\|", "-", record.id)

    print (infile)
    print ("Old record ID: " + record.id)
    print ("New record ID: " + ident)

    subprocess.call (['C:\memboss\sixpack.exe', '-sequence ' + infile, '-outseq ' + outdir + ident + '.sixpack', '-outfile ' + outdir + ident + '.format'])

    print ("Translation of: " + infile + "\nWritten to: " + outdir + ident)
```

Comment: Does it give an error? Is the command exactly the same as you would type it on the command-line?

Comment: Well, not exactly the same... I am using (strings, variables?) such as 'infile', 'outdir' and 'ident' to represent what would be the actual path and filenames that would be typed into command line.  Can the subprocess module handle these strings/ variables?

Comment: Using variables is fine but what I mean is: if I would copy and paste the command from your code (which is a string basically) to the actual command-line, would it work? You may need to specify full paths instead of relative paths for file access to work.

Comment: command line: sixpack -sequence c:\python32\multi.fasta -outseq c:\memboss\OUTSEQ.sixpack -outfile c:\memboss\OUTFILE.sixpack

Comment: What is the difference between a relative path and full path?  As long as the user types the full path when prompted, that full path gets assigned to the variable 'infile', 'outdir', etc...

Comment: A relative path is a part of a full path (such as `folder1\folder2\file.ext`). Anyway, if you run that command, does it work? Is the directory writeable for the output files? Does anything happen that should not happen?

Comment: The command "subprocess.call (['C:\memboss\sixpack.exe', '-sequence c:\python32\multi.fasta -outseq c:\memboss\OUTSEQ.sixpack -outfile c:\memboss\OUTFILE.sixpack'])" does not work when it replaces the above code.

Comment: No, the command does not work if I copy/paste into command line.  That makes sense though, because those variables have no meaning outside of python

Comment: You shouldn't copy/paste with variables of course. I mean the command that your Python code produces. Either way, it doesn't work won't tell us much. Can you try using subprocess to call sixpack without any parameters? If that works, you should get an error from sixpack that it is missing some parameters.

Comment: Is there a method to see what errors are being produced? Or a way to see what the command that Python is producing?

Comment: IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\python32\\myfiles\test\\multi.fasta'..... do the double slashes mean anything?

Comment: You can use `subprocess.check_call` and `subprocess.check_output` to check the output of a function. Also read the last section of http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html as you're using Windows and minor issues can cause the command not to work.

Comment: I've read the entire subprocess document, still can't figure it out.  Anyone have any ideas?  It seems as though sixpack does execute, but no output files are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer..  I was using the wrong syntax to call subprocess.  This is the correct syntax:

```
subprocess.call (['C:\memboss\sixpack.exe', '-sequence', infile, '-outseq', outdir + ident + '.sixpack', '-outfile', outdir + ident + '.format'])
```